Why are Lorentz transformations singular at $i^0$?
On pg. 16 of Strominger's lectures, it is said

Lorentz transformations themselves are not smooth at spatial infinity, because the vector
fields that generate them are singular at $i_0$. A boost toward the north pole in the
future is a boost away from the north pole in the past. The point $i_0$ is the dividing
point of these two different behaviors.

I would like to mathematically prove this claim. But I don't understand, what the phrases "in the past" and "away from the past" means. Thinking that it just means, along $\mathcal{I}^-$ and $\mathcal{I}^+$ respectively, what I tried to do was to express the boost generators near $\mathcal{I}^+$ in terms of $(u,r,z,\bar{z})$ where $z,\bar{z}$ parameterize the celestial spheres, and take $r \to \infty$. Then a boost towards the northpole would be parameterized by $a=(0,0,\eta,0)$ where $\eta$ is the rapidity. And the element obtained by exponentiating the generator of boost $M_{03}$ should be somehow equal to the boost with $-a$, if we express the generator in terms of $(v,r,z,\bar{z})$? Is that the claim, or how one should proceed?

The quoted passage refers to the action of Lorentz transformations on the unphysical space of conformal compactification. There, the spacelike infinity $i^0$ is the “corner” between past and future null infinities (and the phrase “in the past” refers to $\mathscr I^-$) and since Lorentz transformations act on celestial spheres of past and future null infinities differently their action on spacelike infinity, where two null infinities meet, is singular.
On the other hand, if we view spacelike infinity $i^0$ not from viewpoint of conformal compactification but instead resolve it, as discussed in OP's other question, as codimension one manifold (for example as limit of hyperboloids $r^2-t^2=R^2$ as $R\to\infty$), then the action of Lorentz transformations on it would be well defined and perfectly regular. So it would be more correct to say that it is conformal compactification that is singular at $i^0$ rather than Lorentz transformations themselves.

In the first view, how are the action of Lorentz boosts on celestial sphere different? I mean, I know the expression for boosts written in coordinates suitable for $\mathscr{I}^\pm$ respectively, but I can't take the limit $u \to \infty$ or $v \to \infty$ in a meaningful way because $r \to \infty$ by definition of null infinities.

@Sanjana: I can't take the limit … That is why we have unphysical space, so that null infinities are actual surfaces there, past and future null cones emanating from $t=\pm\infty$, $r=0$. The coordinates $t,r$ of Minkowski are connected to null coordinates $U,V$ of unphysical space via $\tan U =t-r$ and $\tan V =t+r$. Note, that angular coordinates are unchanged by conformal compactification (but would be changed by Lorentz transformations).

@Sanjana - There isn't a single celestial sphere. There is a future sphere and a past sphere. Lorentz transformation acts differently on the two spheres.
